# sort 2 array of object in same time in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mergesort

(UPDATED).

I am trying to sort 2 arrays of object in same time.

I have an array of object contain date.

```
firstArray = [{date: timestamp0 ...},
              {date: timestamp1 ...},
              {date: timestamp2 ...},
              {date: timestamp3 ...},
             ]
```

I have a second array with the same length as the first array contains location (x,y).

```
secondArray = [{x: number0 ..., y: number0},
              {x: number0 ..., y: number0},
              {x: number0 ..., y: number0},
              {x: number0 ..., y: number0},
              ]
```

Every object in the first array is related to object in second array that mean:

`firstArray[0]` is related to `secondArray[0]` and same for all.

After sorting first array, output is (example):

```
firstArray = [{date: timestamp3 ...},
              {date: timestamp1 ...},
              {date: timestamp2 ...},
              {date: timestamp0 ...},
             ]
```

I want to sort `secondArray` to be same as `firstArray`, beacuse as I said every object is related.

How to sort the second array in same order like first array?

Sorting `firstArray`:

```
firstArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Comment: i update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the original index before sorting:

```js
const firstArray = [
{ date: "12/12/2021" }, 
{ date: "12/11/2021" },
{ date: "12/13/2021" },
{ date: "12/3/2021"  }];

firstArray.forEach((item, i) => item.orgIdx = i)
console.log(firstArray)

firstArray.sort((a,b)=> new Date(a.date)- new Date(b.date))
console.log(firstArray)


const secondArray = [
{ x: "number12" },
{ x: "number11" },
{ x: "number13" },
{ x: "number3"  }];

const secondArrSorted = new Array(secondArray.length)
firstArray.forEach(({orgIdx},i) => secondArrSorted[i] = secondArray[orgIdx]);
console.log(secondArrSorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically take the indices, sort as wanted and map the values to new arrays.

```
const
    array1 = [], // given data
    array2 = [], // given data
    indices = [...array1.keys()].sort((a, b) => array1[a] - array1[b]), // or other sorting callback
    sortedArray1 = indices.map(i => array1[i]),
    sortedArray2 = indices.map(i => array2[i]);
    
console.log(sortedArray1); // sorted array1
console.log(sortedArray2); // sorted array2
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? It's quite magical.